# Docker - zsh: command not found: mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am running WordPress with `wp-env` and `docker` configuration,
I want to connect to mysql via cli but I keep getting this error:
`zsh: command not found: mysql`

I have tried: `mysql -h 127.0.0.1:3308 -u root -p` and in post 3306 as well

this is my `docker-compose.yaml` file

phpmyadmin works great

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_test
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
volumes:
  testsuite:
`
```

Comment: You don’t have MySQL client installed locally. Try using `docker exec`.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was to execute the following command:

`docker exec -it {container name}  bash -l`